# Adding WPF window without title bar but need to show it when mouse over in xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I tried with removing title bar using WindowStyle="None".But I need to to show and hide the title bar in WPF by mouse over .So how can i proceed in xaml code ?

Comment: Where do you want to mouse over to show the title bar?

Comment: Titlebar is part of the non-client area in WPF so you cannot handle events on it natively. You might be able to do it with Win32 hooks. Different applications are providing functionality you are trying to do by implementing custom title bar so that's the option for you.

Comment: @Siva I need to show it when i mouse over to the top area of the window